# Magento: inconsistent URL rewrites

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

There's a strange behavior with URL rewrites on our Magento installation, and I'm having a hard time believing there's nothing wrong with it. FYI, I currently have...

System --> Configuration --> Catalog --> Catalog --> SEO --> Create Permanent Redirect for URLs if URL Key Changed is "No"

Also

I've already tried re-indexing URL rewrites from System -> Index Management. This does *not* seem to remove rewrites that are already in place.

When I upload a product via a data feed, I leave `url_key` column blank so that Magento can create its own using the products' names. So, if I upload a product named `White Shirt A`, it will create a target-to-request path `catalog/product/view/id/1234` to `mydomain.com/white-whirt-a.html`. However, if I completely delete this product from the admin panel, and re-upload the same data feed I used earlier, Magento does not remove the preview URL mapping to `mydomain.com/white-whirt-a.html`. Instead, it creates a new URL rule to `mydomain.com/white-whirt-a-1.html` (or sometimes `mydomain.com/white-whirt-a-1234.html` using the product ID for some reason). Note that in the admin, the product will have `mydomain.com/white-whirt-a.html` as its URL key, which is not correct.

Some problems:

1. I don't want the `...-1.html` or `...-1234.html` to be created. How do I prevent getting these "hyphen" links?
2. The larger problem is that the `url_key` available in admin and catalog export file display `mydomain.com/white-whirt-a.html` for this product. When the actual URL is `mydomain.com/white-whirt-a-1.html`.. What is going on?
3. When does Magento create a URL rewrite using the product ID? i.e. `mydomain.com/white-whirt-a-1234.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Magento, or at least our current version, does not remove an URL rewrite once it has been created, no matter what the settings are or whether or not the corresponding product exists in the current catalog. So, if you upload a product with ID 1234 and delete this product later on, the URL rewrite remain in place in `core_url_rewrite`. For whatever reason you upload this product again, it will have a new product ID, of course, like 5678, but since the URL rewrite exist from product ID 1234 its name is the same as product ID 1234, you will end up with `...-1.html` for your new rewrite. I've asked Magento to help, but they just don't quite get what I'm trying to explain.. in the meantime, emptying the table `core_url_rewrite` will work for a dev site.

Answer (score 0):

try to reindex your url rewrite:
system > index management [catalog url rewrite]

if you have a lot of product maybe you will get gateway timeout, if that happens you can try to execute it from command line, it is located in:
[magentoRoot]/shell/indexer.php

Comment: already tried that many times. Re-index doesn't seem to remove existing rewrites in core_url_rewrites table.

Comment: do you use any extension? in url rewrite, there is field named type, what is the value? (system / custom / ?)

Comment: No extension for URl rewrites. Which URl rewrite are you referring to? Db table, admin menu, or?

Comment: Both are ok, just the admin menu

Comment: Ah yes, they are all "System." No custom rewrites.

Comment: Uh sorry, I thought you're using CE. I don't know the code difference between CE and Enterprise